# mysql not accepting apostrophe '

Tags: php, sql

need help inputs are not inserted to db when there is an apostrophe in the textfield values, im trying to use the codes below to escape the ' but its not working,

```
function myaddslashes($string){ 
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1){ 
        return $string; 
    } else { 
        return str_replace("'", "''", $string); 
    } 
}
```

ive used this as well to no avail:

```
function check_input($value)
{
// Stripslashes
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {
  $value = stripslashes($value);
  }
// Quote if not a number
if (!is_numeric($value))
  {
  $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
  }
return $value;
}
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    require 'include/DB_Open.php';

    $RemedyTicketNo = $_POST['RemedyTicketNo'];
    $PhoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];
    $Category2 = $_POST['Category2'];
    $Category3 = $_POST['Category3'];
    $Status = $_POST['Status'];
    $Createdate = $_POST['Createdate'];
    $Date = $_POST['Date'];
    $Severity = $_POST['Severity'];
    $BanType = $_POST['BanType'];
    $XiD = $_POST['XiD'];
    $Ticket = $_POST['Ticket'];

    if (isset($RemedyTicketNo)) 
    {
    $sql="INSERT into tbl_main (ars_no, phone_number, category_1, category_2, status, create_date, resolved_date, trouble_type_priority, ban_type, employee_id_name) 
          VALUES ('".$RemedyTicketNo."', '".$PhoneNumber."', '".$Category2."', '".$Category3."', '".$Status."', '".$Createdate."', '".$Date."', '".$Severity."', '".$BanType."', '".$XiD."')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    header("Location: wireless_new.php");
    }

?>
```

P.S...im new to php and sql so im still trying to learn to use sqli...

Comment: Learn mysqli prepared statements if you're trying to learn mysqli - then you don't need to escape, because it's done for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to fixed it by adding mysql_real_escape_string the field which has ' value

```
$RemedyTicketNo = $_POST['RemedyTicketNo'];
    $PhoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];
    $Category2 = $_POST['Category2'];
    $Category3 = **mysql_real_escape_string** ($_POST['Category3']);
    $Status = $_POST['Status'];
    $Createdate = $_POST['Createdate'];
    $Date = $_POST['Date'];
    $Severity = $_POST['Severity'];
    $BanType = $_POST['BanType'];
    $XiD = $_POST['XiD'];
    $Ticket = $_POST['Ticket'];
```

Answer (score 3):

All strings should be escaped using a database-specific function. In your case [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

If you're learning, you're better off starting with MySQLi as the MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. It's no more difficult than the one you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Use query parameters or whatever the php equivalent is called.  Escaping quotes is one of the good things they do for you.

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli will happily accept a single quote if it gets properly escaped.
but for some reason you don't actually apply none of your functions to the input. So, that's the only your problem.

Also note that error_reporting should always be `E_ALL`, not 0

Answer (score 0):

if you are using

(all book's are available) as $subject and you are trying to insert in to mysql

use this

```
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$disc_str = addslashes($subject);
"INSERT INTO table name (subject) value('$disc_str')";
```

it works for me in Textarea with tinymce also